# Adding unexpected characters to result

Tags: c#

I have a simple wpf app function that merges textbox lines before the length is bigger than 4500 then adds the merged strings to a List and repeats that.

```
    public static void MyFunction(string ogContent, TextBox t)
    {
        List<string> splitCheckedContents = new List<string>();

        string[] splitContents = ogContent.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray());

        for (int j = 0; j < splitContents.Length; j++)
        {
            string stackString = "";
            do
            {
                stackString = stackString + "\\n" + splitContents[j++].Replace("\"", "\\\"");
            } while (j < splitContents.Length && (stackString.Length + splitContents[j].Length + 2) < 4500);
            splitCheckedContents.Add(stackString);
        }
        t.Text = "";
        foreach (string s in splitCheckedContents)
        {
            t.Text += s;
        }
    }
```

so when I input

`first
second
third`

I expect the output to be

`splitCheckedContents[0] = "\nfirst\nsecond\nthird"`

but instead I get

`"\nfirst\n\nsecond\n\nthird"`

I must be missing something but can't find the problem.

I need help...

Comment: Hint: You likely have 5 items in splitContents, not 3. The one between "first" and "second" is empty, likewise the one btween "second" and "third" is also empty. I recommend splitting on `new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies with how you're splitting the text:

```
string[] splitContents = ogContent.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray());
```

By calling `.ToCharArray()`, you are providing two different things the string can split on: `\r`, or `\n`. When the split meets `"first\r\nsecond"`, it produces 3 items: `"first"`, `""`, and `"second"`.

There are two ways you can resolve this:

1. Specify `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`: `ogContent.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` - this will remove ant empty entries that result from the split.
2. Change what you're splitting on: `ogContent.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);` - this will split on Windows-style newlines, and Unix-style newlines.

Complete code with option #2:

```
public static void MyFunction(string ogContent, TextBox t)
{
    List<string> splitCheckedContents = new List<string>();

    string[] splitContents = ogContent.Split(ogContent.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    for (int j = 0; j < splitContents.Length; j++)
    {
        string stackString = "";
        do
        {
            stackString = stackString + "\\n" + splitContents[j++].Replace("\"", "\\\"");
        } while (j < splitContents.Length && (stackString.Length + splitContents[j].Length + 2) < 4500);
        splitCheckedContents.Add(stackString);
    }
    t.Text = "";
    foreach (string s in splitCheckedContents)
    {
        t.Text += s;
    }
}
```

Note that you can also use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` with option 2, if desired.

Comment: thank you very much.  I did not know that.. Seems like I have lots to learn